# Reading Excel xlsx file in a Python application using Django

Tags: python-2.7, xlsx

I need to read an `Excel 2007` `XLSX` file in a python application using `django`. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

```
import xlrd
def Get(request):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Users/kamal/Desktop/data.xlsx")
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sales")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading xlsx files using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371163/reading-xlsx-files-using-python)